# Convert List<Map<String, Object>> to Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>> using Java 8 streams API

Tags: java-8, stream

My question is little similar to what has already been asked [here in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34174527/grouping-by-list-of-map-in-java-8). My input is as follows:

```
Map<String, Object> m1 = new HashMap<>();
m1.put("group", "1");
m2.put("A", 10l);
m2.put("B", 20l);
m2.put("C", 100l);

Map<String, Object> m2 = new HashMap<>();
m1.put("group", "1");
m2.put("A", 30l);
m2.put("B", 40l);
m2.put("C", 500l);

List<Map<String, Object>> beforeFormatting = new ArrayList<>();
beforeFormatting.add(m1);
beforeFormatting.add(m2);
```

My expected output is:

```
Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>> afterFormatting;
```

**Output:**

1 -> [m1, m2]

I have tried below, but getting compile errors: seems like I am doing something wrong with mapping:

```
Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>> afterFormatting = beforeFormatting.stream()
                    .collect(groupingBy(map -> map.get("group_id"), toList()));
```

Comment: Error:(114, 33) java: incompatible types: inference variable K has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: java.lang.String
    lower bounds: java.lang.Object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well `map.get("group_id")` returns an `Object`, but you try to map it to a `String`, change the return type:

```
Map<Object, List<Map<String, Object>>> afterFormatting = beforeFormatting.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(map -> map.get("group_id")));
```

And also you can drop `toList`, since it is implicitly used when `groupingBy` with a single parameter is used.

Comment: Wow thanks!! I guess I got a bit lost & my mind went in a different direction. Is it ok to typecast like this : (String)map.get("group_id") ?

Comment: @GauravSaini how about proving the correct types initially?

Comment: '@Eugene my expected key needs to be a String type and I am less keen to keep keys open ended.